# Strange exception behaviour

Tags: python, exception, ioerror, python-3.5

I want to implement an exception displayer and it doesn't work, but I have something different:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/honzik/PycharmProjects/Toy/test.py", line 21, in main
    raise IOError('Foo bar bazooka!')
OSError: Foo bar bazooka!
```

How can be raised an OSError when I specified IOError?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`IOError` is only an alias for `OSError` in Python3, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#concrete-exceptions:

> Changed in version 3.3: `EnvironmentError`, `IOError`, `WindowsError`,
>   `VMSError`, `socket.error`, `select.error` and `mmap.error` have been
>   merged into `OSError`, and the constructor may return a subclass.